# Was that really THE ENTIRE FLEET in Star Trek Picard: Season 3?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

In *Star Trek: Picard* Season 3 Episodes 9 & 10, the viewers are treated to scenes of a very large fleet amassed at Earth for the Frontier Day Celebration. I'm fairly sure I heard repeatedly that the whole fleet would be there, yet Starfleet purportedly has at least thousands of cruisers. Where are all the other ships? Are they gone for some reason?
In one scene in Episode 9 or 10, Picard asks something like "Where is the cavalry?" That alone suggests that the fleet stationed at Earth isn't the whole fleet, but after Picard's question, I seem to remember that someone said something about other ships being busy getting assimilated...or maybe my memory is just being faulty.
So is that the entire fleet or not? Where are the other ships?

Comment: If I recall correctly, they never showed "the full fleet", but only a part of it.

Comment: @Philipp That may be true. At any rate, it doesn't actually make any sense that Starfleet would bring its entire fleet to one location on Frontier Day. Any enemies of the Federation would take advantage of the absence of ships around Federation space to attack numerous places.

Comment: Ok, haven't watched this show at all... but you're telling me there's entire-fleet scenes? *runs to tv*

Comment: @Kalnode I know PIC doesn't have a good repuation, but I still think some parts of it are worth watching.

Comment: It not making sense is evidence that the full fleet was the intention.  Paradoxically.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry Season 3 is substantially better than the previous two.

Comment: @Dennis_E I agree completely. I should have been more specific when I said "some parts."

Comment: What puzzled me most is how long the space dock managed to last. I mean, I know it's big and it's going to be heavily armoured and heavily shielded and it might well be within the shield grid of the planet but that thing was shown taking a constant barrage of fire... _shrugs_

Comment: @JonClements The whole show had so many plot breaches from the start that it's a wonder it finished relatively well.